# How can i emulate the scrolling of sites like Reddit, Twitter and LInkedIn with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, scrollbar, react-component

I want the scroll effect where the sections on the sides scroll to the last, or dont scroll at all but the middle section keeps scrolling. I have seen something similar in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/), [twitter](https://www.twitter.com/) and [linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/).

Heres my code and an image of how it looks so far:

```js
function Body() {
  return (
    <div className="Body">
      <div className="user-menu"></div>

      <main className="timeline">
        <div className="post-box"></div>
        <div className="post"></div>
        <div className="post"></div>
        <div className="post"></div>
        <div className="post"></div>
        <div className="post"></div>
        <div className="post"></div>
        <div className="post"></div>
      </main>

      <div className="discover">
        <div className="discover-box"></div>
        <div className="footer-box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [infinite scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component) component

Comment: Heard of it, i will check it out, thanks!